# What's a better way to strip all tags from a DOM block except for one specific tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an HTML fragment that I would like to parse and remove all html tags except for a specific tag I want to preserve. I already did it but I think there's a better way of doing it.
In the example below I just want to keep the em tag (to preserve emphasized text):

```
html = "<div><b>Info:</b> <p>This is a <em>HTML</em> block that <span>I would like</span> to parse and fix</p></div>";
description = $(html).text();
var ems = $(html).find("em"); // Find all em tags

// Search on the original description for each em text, and add the tag between.
$(ems).each(function(){ 
    description = description.replace(this.innerHTML, "<em>" + this.innerHTML + "</em>");     
});
console.log(description);
```

The result of this code is:

```
Info: This is a <em>HTML</em> block that I would like to parse and fix
```

Any other idea to perform this?

Not necessarily has to be jQuery, could be pure javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to do this

```
html = "<div><b>Info:</b> <p>This is a <em>HTML</em> block that <span>I would like</span> to parse and fix</p></div>";
var $h = $('<div>'+html+'</div>');
$h.find('*:not(em)').contents().unwrap();

console.log($h.html())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gmwJK/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to replace all elements with their contents, except for `<em>`:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = html;
var tags = tmp.getElementsByTagName('*'), l = tags.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( tags[i].tagName == "EM") continue;
    while(tags[i].firstChild) {
        tags[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tags[i].firstChild,tags[i]);
    }
    tags[i].parentNode.removeChild(tags[i]);
}
var result = tmp.innerHTML;
```